# Merging Arrays on values (different keys) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I would like to display a set of answers to a specific question - with different answers based on a country - no problem with the `foreach` side of this.

However, I only have access (in this array - $answers) to an ID value for the country name. This ID will match another Key in a different array ($countries) and I'd like to output the country name instead of the ID value.

Where the [ques_jurisduction] ID matches the term_id value below, I'd like to append and output the value in [name] - essentially allowing me to replace the ID in the output with the correct country name.

`Print_r` for each gives:

**$answers**

```
Array ( [ques_jurisdiction] => 5 [ques_answer] => )
```

**$countries**

```
Array ( [1] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 119 [name] => Austria [slug] => austria [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 119 [taxonomy] => wgd_jurisdiction [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 96 [filter] => raw ) [value] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 119 [name] => Austria [slug] => austria [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 119 [taxonomy] => wgd_jurisdiction [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 96 [filter] => raw ) [0] => 0 [key] => 0 )
```

Any guidance most appreciated. Think I might be getting a bit confused with Taxonomies and sub_fields!

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain by showing some code that you have written so that i can give you the solution. @TomMyatt

Comment: @Tom Myatt, provide a `var_dump()` for `$answers` as well as `$countries` array please.

Comment: Current Code using suggestion below (still getting output of ID + Answer):

http://pastebin.com/1wSn1bXL

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to output `name` of country and you have its `term_id` as in `ques_jurisdiction` index of `$answers` array. I also noticed that your index `1` and `value` contains same values in `$countries` array. If I am right till now then you can achieve what you want like this:

```
foreach($countries['value'] as $obj){
    if($obj->term_id === $answers['ques_jurisdiction']){
       echo $obj->name; //It will output country name, you can as well take it in some variable to use it later on
    }
}
```

I have used `'value'` index, you can as well use index `1` as they both contains same data.

*I hope it helps*